# Может ли быть превосходная степень у слова "неповторимый"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, степени-прилагательных

Корректно ли это предложение:
*Она самое прекрасное, **неповторимое** существо, какое я когда-либо видела*?

Как я понимаю, здесь превосходная степень переносится и на слово "неповторимое"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что предложение можно оставить в авторском варианте, так как второе определение не синоним первого:

**Она самое прекрасное, неповторимое существо, какое я когда-либо видела.**

**Неповторимый** ― это прилагательное, которое имеет следующие значения: **прямое**  (нельзя повторить) и **переносное** (неподражаемый, бесподобный).

**Превосходная степень для второго значения иногда встречается**, например: Он ― **самый неповторимый** (и необъяснимый) обитатель русского литературного Олимпа. [Валерий Сердюченко. Между выморочностью и гениальностью (2003)].

**Примеры на тему:**

«**Прелестнейший** юноша», «**бесподобнейший человек»**, «**замечательнейшая** женщина», ― были обычными эпитетами, употребляемыми Николаем Николаевичем. [Т. Л. Сухотина-Толстая. Друзья Ясной Поляны (1908-1917)]

... вы человек **бесподобнейший**, то-есть не лгущий на каждом шагу, а может быть, и совсем,… [Ф. М. Достоевский. Идиот (1869)]

потом по московским гостиным зациркулировал **бесподобнейший** номер, разыгрываемый Эллисом; [Андрей Белый.  (1929)]

**Из словаря:**

НЕПОВТОРИМЫЙ,  1. Такой, который нельзя повторить, произнести ещё раз. Н-ые слова. Н-ое обвинение. Н-ая брань. // Такой, который больше не повторяется. Н-ое детство. Н-ая молодость. Н-ая любовь. **2. =Неподражаемый**.

НЕПОДРАЖАЕМЫЙ,  **Единственный в своём роде; неповторимый, бесподобный.** Н. мастер пера. Н-ое умение, искусство.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше написать примерно так:

***Она самое прекрасное из существ, которых я когда-либо видела.***

Вместо *которых* можно употребить *что*:

***Она самое прекрасное из существ, что я когда-либо видела.***

Answer (score 2):

А почему нет? Практика показывает, что таки да.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще-то не стоит ничего усиливать, и так хорошо.

Но если рискнуть, то:

*Она самое прекрасное, неповторимейшее существо, какое я когда-либо видела.*

Answer (score 0):

Как я думаю, *неповторимый* — это либо относительное прилагательное, либо страдательное причастие настоящего времени. Естественно, в этих формах никаких степеней сравнения нет.

В слове *неповторимейший* суффикс *-ейш-*, скорее всего, используется только для эмоционального усиления.